# C string compare wont allow space bar

Tags: c, string-comparison

using the cprogrammingsimplified tutorial for writing my own stringcompare.
Finished reformatting it and ran it.
works fine for single words,

But

typing space bar skips the second scan and immediately outputs
'words aren't the same'

anyone any idea how to allow the use of even a single space bar?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mystrcmp(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main(){
    char s1[10], s2[10];
    int flag;

    printf("Type a string of 10\n\n");
    scanf("%s",&s1);
    printf("type another string of 10 to compare\n\n");
    scanf("%s",&s2);

    flag = mystrcmp(s1,s2);

    if(flag==0)
        printf("the words are the same\n\n");

    else
        printf("the words are not the same\n\n");

    return 0;
}

int mystrcmp(char s1[], char s2[]){
    int l=0;

    while (s1[l] == s2[l]) {
        if (s1[l] == '\0' || s2[l] == '\0')
            break;
        l++;
    }

    if (s1[l] == '\0' && s2[l] == '\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please give the two example inputs that don't appear to work

Comment: A space is a delimiter for the scanf function. So only the first word will be put in s1.

Comment: many thanks everyone, just in the middle of other assignments, so will have to get back to all the extra info here!

Answer (score 3):

Use `fgets()` to read full lines, rather than `scanf()` to read space-separated words.

Remember that `fgets()` will include the linefeed in the string, though.

Answer (score 3):

It is not `strcmp` that wouldn't allow space bar, it's `scanf` with `%s` format specifier. The input is truncated at the space, so the second string that you read is actually the continuation of the first string.

You can fix this by using `%9[^\n]` instead of `%s` in your format specifier:

```
printf("Type a string of 10\n\n");
scanf("%9[^\n]",s1); //s1 is char [10]
printf("type another string of 10 to compare\n\n");
scanf("%9[^\n]",s2); //s2 is char [10]
```

`9` limits input to nine characters, because you are using a ten-character buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Many answers have told you that `scanf("%s",s1)` only reads word by word. This is because by default `scanf("%s",s1)` is delimited by all white spaces, this includes `\t`, `\n`, `<space>`, or any other you can think of.

What `scanf("%[^\n]s",s1)` does is set the delimiter to `\n`. So in effect reads all other spaces.

@dasablinklight has also specified a 9 before the `'[^\n]'` this denotes that `scanf()` takes 9 values from input buffer.

IMO `scanf()` is a really nice function due to it's *hidden* features. I suggest you read more about it in it's [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you type `abc def` on the first line, the first `scanf("%s", s1)` (no ampersand required — it should be absent) reads `abc` and the second reads `def`.  And those are not equal.  Type `very very` and you'd find the words are equal.  `%s` stops reading at a space.

Your buffers of size 10 are too small for comfort.

Fix: read lines (e.g. `char s1[1024], s2[1024];`) with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX's [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), remove trailing newlines (probably: `s1[strcspn(s1, "\n")] = '\0';` is a reliable way to do it) and then go ahead compare the lines.